# Serialization with Hierarchy and inheritance System.Text.Json

Tags: .net, serialization, system.text.json

Can you explain why serialization of 'ILevel2' do not include the 'ILevel1' property ?

`Serialize(level2)`, I expect to have `{"Scrore":10,"Name":"Benjamin","City":"Lille"}`

How to have it ?
Note im using the .net JSON serializer : `using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer;`

```
var obj = new FullClass() { Name = "Benjamin", Scrore = 10, City = "Lille"};

ILevel1 level1 = obj as ILevel1;
ILevel2 level2 = obj as ILevel2;


Console.WriteLine(Serialize(obj)); //==>  {"Scrore":10,"Name":"Benjamin","City":"Lille"}
Console.WriteLine(Serialize(level1)); //==> {"Name":"Benjamin","City":"Lille"}
Console.WriteLine(Serialize(level2)); //==> {"Scrore":10}


public interface ILevel1
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
}

public interface ILevel2 : ILevel1
{
    int Scrore { get; set; }
}

public class FullClass : ILevel2
{
    public int Scrore { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks to be the same issue as [Property from a superinterface missing when convert Interface to json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73812109).

Answer (score 1):

When you cast `level2` to `FullClass` it works. I think this has to do with the serializer not being able to process inherited values from interfaces. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41749) github issue.

I saw that the changes referred to in the github issue were merged into the main dotnet branche in november of 2022. From my understanding they will be release with .NET 8.

For now you should consider casting your Interface to the Fullclass object. Or you could use the newtonsoft json serializer which should be able to handle this properly

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 7 was `[JsonDerivedType]` introduced.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

```
[JsonPolymorphic(UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FallBackToNearestAncestor)]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Level1), typeDiscriminator: "base")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Level2 ), typeDiscriminator: "child")]
public interface ILevel1
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
}

public interface ILevel2 : ILevel1
{
    int Scrore { get; set; }
}
```

New we can do `JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Level2{Scrore = 42})`